# Efficient column MultiIndex ordering

Tags: pandas, dataframe, sorting, multi-index

I have this dataframe :

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({'A' : [2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000], 
                       'B' : ["A+", 'B+', "A+", "B+", "A+", "B+"],
                       'C' : ["M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F"],
                       'D' : [1, 5, 3, 4, 2, 6],
                       'Value' : [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16] }).set_index((['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']))

df = df.unstack(['C', 'D']).fillna(0)
```

And I'm wondering is there is a more elegant way to order the columns MultiIndex that the following code :

```
# rows ordering
df = df.sort_values(by = ['A', "B"], ascending = [True, True])
# col ordering
df = df.transpose().sort_values(by = ["C", "D"], ascending = [False, False]).transpose()
```

Especially I feel like the last line with the two transpose si far more complex than it should be. I tried using sort_index but wasn't able to use it in a MultiIndex context (for both lines and columns).

Comment: `df.sort_index(level=[0,1],axis=1,ascending=False)` ?

Comment: df.sort_index(level=[0,1],axis=1,ascending=[True, False])  does the trick. You can post it as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use sort index on both levels:

```
out = df.sort_index(level=[0,1],axis=1,ascending=[True, False])
```

Comment: indeed, but different with different filtering on each level (one ascending, one descending)

Answer (score 1):

I can use

```
axis=1
```

And therefore the last line become

```
df = df.sort_values(axis = 1, by = ["C", "D"], ascending = [True, False])
```